# How to format chocolatey params in puppet manifest

Tags: puppet, chocolatey

The following choco install command works fine:

```
choco Install 'InstallTest' -y --source 'C:\installtest' --params="'/serverinstance:MyServer /buildtype:OTP'"
```

I now have the following, in a Puppet manifest:

```
package { 'InstallTest':
  ensure            => installed,
  install_options   => ['-params','"', /serverinstance:MyServer, /buildtype:OTP, '"'],
  source            => 'c:\installtest',
}
```

I thought that I was correctly covering spaces with commas, etc, but puppet parser throws the following error:

```
puppet : [1;31mError: Could not parse for environment production: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8[0m
```

Without the install_options line, it compiles fine.

What should the correct syntax be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

> ```
>   install_options   => ['-params','"', /serverinstance:MyServer, /buildtype:OTP, '"'],
> ```

Although Puppet can accept [bare words as strings](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_data_string.html#bare-words), there are limitations on the content of such strings.  The one relevant here is that they must

> Begin with a lower case letter, and contain only letters, digits, hyphens (`-`), and underscores (`_`).

Thus, you're looking for this:

```
  install_options   => ['-params', '"', '/serverinstance:MyServer', '/buildtype:OTP', '"'],
```

Overall, its better style to quote substantially all strings, whether they need it or not.  That's clearer, and it will keep you out of trouble.